# How can I open an exe file right inside the browser?

Tags: silverlight, flash, web-applications

I am developing a project in which I am required to open an exe file (i.e. notepad) right inside the browsers window. The solution can be in any programming tool / language. I have tried a sample program in VB.NET and it is working. (see the figure attached below)
[image: output]

Same thing I want to achieve in web applications. Any blog / tutorial / code snippet will be helpful....

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, this is why there is such a disctinction between web and desktop. The only solution I see (except from rewriting the exe application in java/AS/js) would be to stream the application as a VNC would do. Display output is sent to the client as a movie and user input is sent back to the server. This may be a bad and very heavy to deploy idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is really possible due to the nature of client server programming... I liked the idea of VNC of @kodiak answer but I don't think u need that kind of solution...